# How do I reference top UIElement in ControlTemplate?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, controltemplate

In my custom control I have ControlTemplate propety

```
public ControlTemplate ControlTemplate
```

It can be something like this:

```
<map:IdattMapLayer.ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Canvas
            DataContext="{Binding
                Converter={StaticResource ObjectToTrackedAssetConverter}}">
            <Button                                
                Style="{StaticResource LooklessButtonStyle}"
                Width="{Binding PushpinWidth}" Height="{Binding PushpinWidth}"
                Margin="{Binding PushpinMargin}"
                Command="{Binding
                    Path=DataContext.SelectedPushpinChangedCommand,
                    ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                Cursor="Hand">
                <Ellipse
                  Width="{Binding PushpinWidth}"
                  Height="{Binding PushpinWidth}"
                  Stroke="Black"
                  Fill="{Binding IsGPSDataRecent,
                      Converter={StaticResource BoolToGreenRedBrushConverter}}"
                  StrokeThickness="1">
                </Ellipse>
            </Button>
        </Canvas>
    </ControlTemplate>
</map:IdattMapLayer.ControlTemplate>
```

I would like to set `Canvas`'s data context myself rather than doing it in XAML.

So, If I have ControlTemplate - how do I find first child (Canvas in this case) programmatically?

Comment: `ControlTemplate.VisualTree.FirstChild`

Comment: ControlTemplate doesn't have VisualTree property..

Comment: LOL, I just copied it straight form Visual Studio??, what .NET framework are you using? seems to be in the documentation too, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: oh, sorry missed that

Comment: Usually one rarely needs a `ControlTemplate`, maybe a DataTemplate is more suitable? How are you using the template property?

Comment: And also, why not just set the data context of the control that you're applying the `ControlTemplate` to?  The ControlTemplate will inherit that DataContext directly.

Comment: I'm wrapping 3rd party control. ControlTemplate visualizes one of the array elements, I need to bind my object directly. ControlTemplate being passed on into 3rd party and I use converter right now to convert object.

Answer (score 1):

1) set x:Name attribute for Canvas.

2) override OnApplyTemplate.

3) use (Canvas)GetTemplateChild("CanvasName") for get Canvas.

ofcourse this class should  inherit from Control.